# Any way to edit and/or add autocorrect entries?

Tags: macos, dictionary, autocorrect

Perhaps a silly question: But let's say I have a word that I love to misspell. Okay, maybe not exactly. But maybe Lion has a problem with ReiserFS and keeps:

1. Suggesting something else (autocorrect).
2. Marks it as incorrect.

Is there anyway to:

1. Stop Lion from suggesting something else for ReiserFS. (I still want to keep autocorrect on!)
2. Add this word to the dictionary so that it's no longer marked as misspelled.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Learn spelling.​​​​​​​​​

[image]

Comment: What about autocorrect? ReiserFS may be a bad example. But what if autocorrect is giving me another word as I type ReiserFS?

Comment: Once Lion learned a word, it should no longer bother you with autocorrections while typing it. (I'm not entirely sure what you mean, though)

Comment: This is going to sound really lame, but what can I say. I was asking for a friend and I assumed he already tried this. He did not. :-) Thanks!

Comment: voidStern's answer is not correct in my experience (at least with Mountain Lion) -- I've added words to the User dictionary and it will still be autocorrected to other words.

Comment: Your link was broken and didn't exist on archive.org. If you still have the image or remember what it was and can take it again, can you reupload it using the official image uploader?